# Почему «Первый запрос к API» users.get возвращает city.id, но не city.title?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

В настройках iFrame-приложения для ВКонтакте в качестве [Первого запроса к API](https://vk.com/page-1_8813441) я указал:

```
method=users.get&user_ids={viewer_id}&fields=sex,city,photo_big&format=JSON&v=5.52
```

[image: скриншот]

В официальной документации [users.get](http://vk.com/dev/users.get) точно такой же запрос возвращает:

```
response: [{
    id: 597xxxxx,
    first_name: 'Alexander',
    last_name: 'Farber',
    city: {
        id: 1945522,
        title: 'Bochum'
    },
    photo_50: 'http://cs5344.vk....1265/e_9ae5906d.jpg',
    verified: 0
}]
```

А вот в мой PHP-скрипт (он же "Адрес IFrame" в настройках) приходят следующие данные по HTTP GET:

```
[api_result] => {"response":[{
    "uid":597xxxxx,
    "first_name":"Alexander",
    "last_name":"Farber",
    "sex":2,
    "city":1945522,
    "photo_big":"http:\/\/cs5344.vk.me\/u59751265\/a_047c17e7.jpg"
}]}
```

То есть приходят только данные `city.id` (1945522), в то время как мне нужен `city.title` (Bochum).

Конечно, можно произвести **второй** вызов к API и получить через [database.getCitiesById](http://vk.com/dev/database.getCitiesById) (или старую функцию `getCities`) нужное название города... но почему оно не приходит сразу?

Comment: Покажите ваш запрос, версия указана в запросе? ибо по умолчанию стоит не самая последняя

Comment: Я добавил скриншот настроек в мой вопрос: у меня нет другого запроса кроме вышеуказанного **"Первого запроса к API"** в Настройках приложения, и я сразу парсю $data = json_decode($_GET['api_result'], true); $me = $data['response'][0]; print_r($me);